# supervisord exiting with ENOEXEC

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to run a java process with supervisord and am getting:

```
couldn't exec /var/application/start_tester: ENOEXEC
```

The contents of start_tester is:

```
java -Duser.dir=/var/application/ -cp /var/application/application.jar:/var/application/toepoke.jar com.application.Application
```

When I run the script from the console the app runs as expected. Here is my supervisor config

```
[program:application_tester]
directory=/var/application
command=/var/application/start_tester         ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
log_stdout=true             ; if true, log program stdout (default true)
log_stderr=true             ; if true, log program stderr (def false)
logfile=/var/log/application_tester.log
```

When I run the script from the console this is the output:

```
[root@monitor application]# ./start_tester 
20131009 203657: application starting up.
20131009 203657 (33): version 2.2.3
```

Answer (score 61):

Your file needs to be executable. So either:

1. You should `chmod +x` it to set the executable bit.
2. Put a shebang at the start of the file. Not having this is what caused the `ENOEXEC`.

or

1. Modify your config file to something like `command=sh /var/application/start_tester`.

Comment: In my case, shebang was missing.

Comment: Thanks Gagandeep. shebang was the missing line for me too. 

Let me also add that after including the shebang line, you need re-enable and restart supervisor for it to work: 

sudo systemctl enable supervisor 
sudo systemctl restart supervisor

Answer (score 20):

In most cases a shebang is usually missing.

```
  - #!/usr/bin/env bash
  - #!/bin/bash
  - #!/bin/sh
  - #!/bin/sh -
```

Once you add the shebang to your gunicorn_start file (in case of DJANGO),
restart the supervisor

```
sudo systemctl enable supervisor 
sudo systemctl restart supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by using Apple M1 chip to compile a go binary, but then running it on amd64 (in AWS).

See this stack overflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74731135/1068446