# Django Supervisor FATAl Exited too quickly how to improve?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, supervisord

I am using supervisor in django  my supervisor  got error. 
my server on Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 i use, nginx, gunicortn, supervisor, postgresql.

> `FATAl Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`.
>
> if you have some ideas how to fix this, please let me know your
>   thoughts

This is my supervisor file.

```
[program:chart_app]
command = /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start
user = chart 
stdout_logfile = /webapps/chart_app/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true 
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

error in logs

```
> supervisor: couldn't exec /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start:
> ENOEXEC supervisor: child process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't
> exec /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned supervisor: couldn't exec
> /webapps/chart_app/bin/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC supervisor: child
> process was not spawned
```

gunicrotn_start

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="chart_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/chart_app/src             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/chart_app/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=chart                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=src.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=src.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [supervisord exiting with ENOEXEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285666/supervisord-exiting-with-enoexec)