# AWS ECS exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am pretty new to this Docker world and I am trying to deploy an image (nodejs-typescript service) from aws ECR to aws ECS but when I create the service inside the cluster this error appears and the taks never gets running:

```bash
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig*.json ./

RUN yarn install --quiet

RUN yarn global add pm2

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "build/src/localServer.js"]
```

It is working fine on my pc when I build the image and run it:

```bash
(base) MacBook-Pro api % docker run -it -p 3000:3000 api-dev                                    
2022-12-06T15:35:27: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2022-12-06T15:35:27: PM2 log: App [localServer:0] starting in -fork mode-
2022-12-06T15:35:27: PM2 log: App [localServer:0] online
Connected to my_mongo_db_cluster
  Server ready at: http://localhost:3000/
```

The task definition is running on Linux/X86_64.

Any suggestions or tips to find out what is the problem? Thanks!

EDIT: when I add an ENTRYPOINT to my Dockerfile like this

```
# same steps

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

ENTRYPOINT ["pm2-runtime", "build/src/localServer.js"]
```

it throw this error `exec /usr/local/bin/pm2-runtime: exec format error`. The same happens when I change `pm2-runtime` to `node`

```
# same steps

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "build/src/localServer.js"]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How did you create service?

Comment: Just specifying LUNCH TYPE as FARGATE and assigning my task definition I previously created. The task is also created as app_environment=FARGATE

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. It was my Apple M1 chip doing its incompatibility magic. For those who has the same problem, just adding the platform `--platform=linux/amd64` in your Dockerfile seems to solve the problem:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:lts-alpine

# more instructions...
```

Comment: Same here, I had to build and push the image again and it worked

Comment: This fixed my problem as well! I had been troubleshooting this for a while too!

Comment: Problems because I've omitted the platform spec when building images on the M1 have bitten me on so many occasions. Like you, this occurence was also found when I tried to run my container in Amazon EKS. Thanks for this.

Comment: This needs a million +1s. I had been hitting this a bit for some other tech and kept trying to figure out what was really going on. I was starting to think that maybe I was getting deployed to Graviton instances by mistake. This answered EVERYTHING for me.

Comment: I've lost two days on research and then I've tried this and it worked! I owe you a beer!

Comment: Build once, run anywhere!

Comment: This was helpful in resolving a different issue, where we're using AWS CodeBuild to build the docker image but that same image wouldn't start successfull in ECS. In this case, the environment was set to ARM when it should have been X86_64. Updating the environment resolved the issue